# copy member variable into byte vector

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, copy, memcpy

I want to copy a 64-bit member variable into a vector byte by byte.

Please avoid telling me to use bit operation to extract each byte and then copy them into vector.

I want to do this by one line.

I use memcpy and copy methods, but both of them failed.

Here is the sample code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <cstdint>
#include <cstring>

using namespace std;

class A {
 public:
  A()
  : eight_bytes_data(0x1234567812345678) {
  }

  void Test() {
    vector<uint8_t> data_out;
    data_out.reserve(8);
    memcpy(data_out.data(),
           &eight_bytes_data,
           8);
    cerr << "[Test]" << data_out.size() << endl;
  }

  void Test2() {
    vector<uint8_t> data_out;
    data_out.reserve(8);
    copy(&eight_bytes_data,
         (&eight_bytes_data) + 8,
         back_inserter(data_out));
    cerr << "[Test2]" << data_out.size() << endl;
    for (auto value : data_out) {
      cerr << hex << value << endl;
    }
  }

 private:
  uint64_t eight_bytes_data;
};

int main() {
  A a;
  a.Test();
  a.Test2();
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: `std::vector<>::reserve` only allocates space, it does not tell the vector how many elements will be inserted into the vector. And since you are using memcpy to do the actual copying, the vector doesn't know that the copied bytes are now in use.

Comment: Part of the failure in the first case is your understanding of how `reserve()` works, and how it affects the underlying vector. And in the second case, typed-pointer arithmetic is crucial to understanding where the wheels fell off there. `(&eight_bytes_data) + 8` isn't eight bytes past the base address of `eight_bytes_data`, its eight `uint64_t` elements (and quite deep into the land of *undefined behavior*, since you have only *one* such element).

Comment: @evan I use `resize()` to replace `reserve()` in the first case. It works.

Comment: @WhozCraig In the second case, I change `(eight_bytes_data) + 8` to `(eight_bytes_data) + 1`. But it still doesn't work.

Comment: Assuming you meant `(&eight _bytes_data) + 1` , that's because the types are still wrong. I never said the `8` was wrong. The *type* of the pointers you're passing are wrong for the copy operation you're performing.

Comment: @WhozCraig OK. I'm working on the type.

Comment: @Christophe why are you just [doing this as a function](http://ideone.com/heURzp) ? And honestly, a `std::array<uint8_t, sizeof(uint64_t)>` would be a better fit imho.

Comment: @WhozCraig Actually, I simplify the situation in the sample code. I'm working on writing a binary format into file. So the buffer size is variable according to how many bytes need to be written.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the others already showed where you were getting wrong, there is a one line solution that is dangeurous.

First you need to make sure that you vector has enough size to receive 8 bytes. Something like this:

```
data_out.resize(8);
```

The you can do a reinterpret_cast to force your compiler to interpret those 8 bytes from the vector to be seen as an unique type of 8 bytes, and do the copy

```
*(reinterpret_cast<uint64_t*>(data_out.data())) = eight_bytes_data;
```

I can't figure out all the possibilities of something going wrong. So use at your own risk.

Comment: Thank you for your solution. I got it. Could you please tell me how to modify the second case to let it work? Thanks.

Comment: @Christophe As WhozCraig said, your types are wrong. To correct them, you need to do the same dangerous operation that I do here. You need to reinterpret your int64_t as int8_t. Something likes this: `copy(reinterpret_cast<uint8_t*>(&eight_bytes_data),  reinterpret_cast<uint8_t*>(&eight_bytes_data) + 8, back_inserter(data_out));`

Comment: The `std::copy` is a helluva lot safer than the direct assignment. Direct assignment to a buffer you're convincing the compiler is a uint64_t (which may have alignment restrictions on the target platform) is playing with fire in terms of portability. single-byte copying to a `uint8_t` target sequence will work and will not introduce the potential of a panic.

Comment: @WhozCraig Thanks. This is what I was expecting to read here. Where it could be wrong (as I had explained in the answer). Indeed, why do you not post your commentary and ideone code as an answer. It is better than mine

Comment: @WhozCraig understates the issue – using `reinterpret_cast` here is flat-out UB. `memcpy` is exactly the correct solution; the only fix needed in the question's code was `reserve`->`resize`.

Comment: @ildjarn Yeah, I concur. I leave hand optimizations like this to implementation intrinsics precisely because I prefer not to roll the UB dice. If the implementation authors for a specific platform can optimize this by slamming dwords or qwords around and strip out the loops, so be it. I prefer portable, defined behavior.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to work with the bytes of another type structure, you could use a char* to manipulate each byte:

```
void Test3()
{
    vector<uint8_t> data_out;
    char* pbyte = (char*)&eight_bytes_data;

    for(int i = 0; i < sizeof(eight_bytes_data); ++i)
    {
        data_out.push_back(pbyte[i]);
    }

    cerr << "[Test]" << data_out.size() << endl;
```

}

Unfortunately, you requested a one-line-solution, which I don't think is viable.

Comment: Thank you for your help. But I'm finding more concise solution.

Answer (score 0):

If you are interested in more generic version:

```
namespace detail
{
    template<typename Byte, typename T>
    struct Impl
    {
        static std::vector<Byte> impl(const T& data)
        {
                std::vector<Byte> bytes;
                bytes.resize(sizeof(T)/sizeof(Byte));
                *(T*)bytes.data() = data;
                return bytes;
        }
    };

    template<typename T>
    struct Impl<bool, T>
    {
        static std::vector<bool> impl(const T& data)
        {
            std::bitset<sizeof(T)*8> bits(data);
            std::string string = bits.to_string();
            std::vector<bool> vector;
            for(const auto& x : string)
                vector.push_back(x - '0');
            return vector;
        }
    };
}

template<typename Byte = uint8_t,
         typename T>
std::vector<Byte> data_to_bytes(const T& data)
{
    return detail::Impl<Byte,T>::impl(data);
}

int main()
{
    uint64_t test = 0x1111222233334444ull;

    for(auto x : data_to_bytes<bool>(test))
        std::cout << std::hex << uintmax_t(x) << " ";
    std::cout << std::endl << std::endl;

    for(auto x : data_to_bytes(test))
        std::cout << std::hex << uintmax_t(x) << " ";
    std::cout << std::endl << std::endl;

    for(auto x : data_to_bytes<uint16_t>(test))
        std::cout << std::hex << uintmax_t(x) << " ";
    std::cout << std::endl << std::endl;

    for(auto x : data_to_bytes<uint32_t>(test))
        std::cout << std::hex << uintmax_t(x) << " ";
    std::cout << std::endl << std::endl;

    for(auto x : data_to_bytes<uint64_t>(test))
        std::cout << std::hex << uintmax_t(x) << " ";
    std::cout << std::endl << std::endl;

}
```

Output:

```
0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 1 0 1
0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0

44 44 33 33 22 22 11 11

4444 3333 2222 1111

33334444 11112222

1111222233334444
```

Comment: Happy to see this powerful solution. Thanks